# How to design a multi-node application network layer?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, connection, boost-asio

I need to implement a mater election lib based on PaxosLease.And meeting problem on network layer design.

The network core requirements as follows:

- Each node is both a server and a client
- System can work without some nodes online

according to the requirements above, I design the network layer as follow:

- Use TCP to transport msg.
- Each node listen on named port to accept connection(called ReadSession), these connections will only read msg.
- Connect to the other nodes by anonymous port(called WriteSession), these connections will only write msg.

The design maybe looks ok. Because some nodes can off-line at the beginnning, problem occurs: ReadSession can be created by new online node connecting to node, and how can I create WriteSession to the new online node? we can't know the off-line node when to online, and we can only know its anonymous port by accepting new connection from new online node rather than its listen port.

It's really a design problem for me. I have these two ideas at the moment:

- Try to use UDP to transport msg
- register `async_connect` again in `Asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_connect` when throw exception(means connect failed).But this idea still has problems:

  1. `asio::io_context` spend to much IO resource on `async_connect`'s handler.
  2. we can't make WriteSession be ready immediately when we need write msg because of async op.

So, I want a design that can prepare WriteSession ok immediately when new online node connect to present node.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the network topology you create is a distributed system. And the problem you faced has been solved by many famous applications such as zookeeper and chubby.

If you don't want to be so complex, maybe you can try to use some broadcast protocol like LSD in LAN, or using DHT in WLAN.

Comment: yeah, I know this problem has been solved by Zookkeeper/Chubby.I want to know is there an design can connecnt the new online node immediately when it's online? If not, UDP can also satisfy the requirement, but need other thing, like heartbeat etc.Well ,thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you want to connect new node "immediately", then the node must send broadcast to all  old nodes to declare his existence. Then you at least need a hertbeat design and a broadcast design. The broadcast I have said above. The duty of hearbeat is to check if nodes are alive, and the broadcast is used to get new one.